# Generating a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to create this form of multidimensional array in PHP:

```
$data = array(
'legend' => array('Series 1', 'Series 2', 'Series 3',),
'data 1' => array(10, 7, 5),
'data 2' => array(20, 60, 3),
'data 3' => array(50, 33, 7),
'data 4' => array(25, 0, 14));
```

but I am not able to make it dynamically. The legend is going to be hard-coded, but data1, data2 ... are dynamic. I am a PHP newbie and I need to solve this please.

I have made the legend array statically, but I need help for the rest!

Comment: how are you pulling the data in dynamically?  From a database?

Comment: @glambert yes i am getting the data from DB

Comment: Show your database query and sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about making use of [array_unshift()](https://www.php.net/array_unshift):

```
<?php

$data = array();
$headings = array('legend' => array('Series 1','Series 2','Series 3'));

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb;charset=utf8', 'myuser', 'mypass');

$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE field = ?');
if($stmt->execute(array($_REQUEST['value']))){
    $i=1;
    while($row=$stmt->fetch()){
        $data[]=array('data ' . $i => array(
            $row->series1,
            $row->series2,
            $row->series3,
        ));
        $i++;
    }
}

array_unshift($data, $headings);
print_r($data);

?>
```

Comment: Instead of `array_unshift`, why not just use that as the initial row in the array? `$data = array('legend' => array('Series 1','Series 2','Series 3'));`

Comment: In fact, your use of `array_unshift` is wrong. It be nested an extra level.

Answer (score 1):

try this. It is general form as you didn't give result structure

```
$result = 'result from database';
$data['legend'] = array('Series 1', 'Series 2', 'Series 3');
$i = 1;
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$data['data'.$i] = array('asdfas','asda','asdasd');
$i+=1;
}

print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
$db = mysqli_connect('host', 'username', 'password', 'database');
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    exit("Failed to connect to database.");

$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
$data = array('legend' => array('Series 1','Series 2','Series 3'));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
    $data['data ' . count($data)] = $row;
```